# Show Flutter dialog only on part of the screen

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, android-alertdialog

On a Dialog, you can set `barrierDismissible` to false if you want to disable touch events outside of the dialog. However, it is possible to listen to these touch events only on some part of the screen eg. `AppBar`?

I made an illustration to help you understand my problem.[image]

Comment: Did you find any answer to that?

Answer (score -1):

We know that everything is Widget, so we can exploit this property to create our own Dialog. There are some possibilities to do what you want, but it depends a lot on the dynamics of your application. I think it would do as follows:

Calling the dialog as follows:

```
showDialog(
   context: context,
   barrierDismissible: false,
   child: DialogFeelingCalendar(),
);
```

And it uses a widget to personalize. Like this:

```
class DialogFeelingCalendar extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _DialogFeelingCalendarState createState() => _DialogFeelingCalendarState();
    }

class _DialogFeelingCalendarState extends State<DialogFeelingCalendar> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(
           "Title",
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Center(
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            height: 50,
            width: 50,
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
}
```

I hope you can customize it for your use. Tell me if you need more details.