# Is there a way to show a dialog "beneath" the app bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to show a dialog that slides out from beneath the appbar, which darkens the entire screen except the app bar. [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63161345/show-flutter-dialog-only-on-part-of-the-screen) vaguely describes what I want, though I am also looking to have the dialog slide down from the top (and have the app bar cover it).

AFAIK there are ways to slide in bottom sheets under the bottom navigation bar, but no equivalent behavior for the top app bar.

Comment: So did you try something?

Comment: The best thing I could do was render a stack as the contents and manually darken the contents when my dialog is showing, but this wasn't the best approach as there was some weirdness where there would be a tiny gap in darkening between the navbar and the page content

Comment: Please also share your codes and output that you didn't want it to be

Comment: In pseudocode, I had

```Scaffold(
    bottomNavigationBar:Stack(children:[someWidget, someTranslucentBarrier])
    body: Stack(children:[someContent, someTranslucentBarrier]))
```

This was causing there to be a thin, 1-2 pixel tall area between the bottom navigation bar and the body that was not covered by the barrier.

However, I just solved this by making the bottom navigation bar barrier a Positioned with top = -5 instead of top = 0.

Comment: Please add it to your original question post~ this way you can attract community